# Select SUM from two other tables

Tags: sql, select, sum

I have this query and successfully gets the `totstock`

```
SELECT p.pid,p.product_name,SUM(s.qty) as totstock
FROM tblproducts p
LEFT JOIN tblstocks s ON s.pid=p.pid
GROUP BY p.pid
```

but when I tried to join my second table it gets wrong total `totstock` and `totsales`
I have this query but i think it is wrong

```
SELECT p.pid,p.product_name,SUM(s.qty) as totstock,SUM(sl.qty) as totsale
FROM tblproducts p
LEFT JOIN tblstocks s ON s.pid=p.pid
LEFT JOIN tbls sl ON sl.pid=p.pid
GROUP BY p.pid
```

Products - tblproducts

```
pid  |   product_name
 1   |  pencil
 2   |  paper
```

Stocks - tblstocks

```
 pid  |  qty 
 1    |   1
 1    |   3
 1    |   5
```

Sales - tbls

```
 pid  |  qty
  1   |   2
  1   |   1
```

The Result i want is

```
pid  | name    | totstock | totsales
 1   |  pencil |    9     |    3  
 2   |  paper  |  NULL    |  NULL
```

Comment: the `totstock` and `totsales` is more than the result i want. i think doubled or tripled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.pid,p.product_name,totstock, totsale
FROM tblproducts p
LEFT JOIN (Select pid, Sum(qty) as totstock from tblstocks group by pid)  s ON s.pid=p.pid
LEFT JOIN (Select pid, Sum(qty) as totsale from tbls group by pid) sl ON sl.pid=p.pid
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5f03/1)

Comment: thank you sir!!! it gets now the correct value.. i dont have idea that i can select also in `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

> Try a group by on p.product_name also. I think that will fix the
>   issue.